# Django WSGI daemon mode synchronization of requests

Tags: django, synchronization, request, daemon, wsgi

Running appache2 with the following /etc/httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=pq group=pq processes=2 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    LogLevel debug

    <Directory /django/myapp/apache/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /django/myapp/apache/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

where this is my /django/myapp/apache/django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/django')
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/django'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I have the following view:

```
def sleep(request):
    print >> sys.stderr, '{', os.getpid()
    time.sleep(5)
    print >> sys.stderr, '}', os.getpid()
    return index(request)
```

I make 4 concurrent requests and my error log shows:

```
[Wed Jan 12 12:59:56 2011] [error] {17160
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:01 2011] [error] }17160
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:01 2011] [error] {17157
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:06 2011] [error] }17157
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:06 2011] [error] {17160
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:11 2011] [error] }17160
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:11 2011] [error] {17157
[Wed Jan 12 13:00:16 2011] [error] }17157
```

Basically my requests were synchronized per webserver (not even per
process).

Why is this?

Edit: This is a single CPU machine and Apache2 is compiled with
prefork MMP.  My client was 4 tabs in Chrome.  Interesting, when I try
this with curl I get the expected:

```
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:18 2011] [error] {17160
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:18 2011] [error] {17157
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:23 2011] [error] }17160
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:23 2011] [error] {17160
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:23 2011] [error] }17157
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:23 2011] [error] {17157
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:28 2011] [error] }17160
[Wed Jan 12 18:10:28 2011] [error] }17157
```

Edit2: Looks like this is an issue with Chrome synchronizing requests.  My (limited) tests showed that this only happens with Chrome and only when tabs are used.  Multiple requests within a single tab are asynchronous.

Comment: Insufficient information. What HTTP client were you using and how were you testing this? What Apache MPM are you using and what are the MPM settings for it?

Comment: Good point Graham.  I updated my post.

Comment: Additionally - Are you using timers to make the requests in the background tabs? If so, background tabs have a forced minimum time of something like 1 second in Chrome / Safari which may be related.